# Merge the data of two arrays of hashes based on values

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash, merge

I want to join two arrays. Both arrays contain hashes that have a single key in common: `object_id`.

```
data1 = [
  {"pid"=>"126199850741820_2172905", "object_id"=>606621809366286, "xcoord"=>81.885856079404, "ycoord"=>51.116625310174},
  {"pid"=>"126199850741820_2172905", "object_id"=>606621809366286, "xcoord"=>81.885856079404, "ycoord"=>51.116625310174}
]
data2 = [
  {"object_id"=>606621809366286, "name" => "123"},
  {"object_id"=>606621809366286, "name" => "321"}
]
```

I want to merge the data together based on matching the two `object_id`'s. Array `data1` has a hash that contains the key `"object_id"` with the value `"606621809366286"` as does `data2`. I need to merge these two hashes together and output a new hash with the data from the rest of the two hashes.

If there are other key/value pairs that are not the same in the dataset, then it does not matter. I just need to match on those `object_ids`.

Comment: what your expected output?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "based on matching the two object_id's".  Can you elaborate?

Comment: sorry, So array data1 has a hash within it that contains the key "object_id" => "606621809366286" as does data2. I need to merge these two hashes together and output a new hash with the data from the rest of the two hashes. Hope thats a bit clearer.

Comment: You left out a lot of information. Do you want to group by ID or dedupe? What if there are other key/value pairs in the hash that differ even though the object_ids are the same?

Comment: I've updated the question with some of this info.

Comment: not clear still, what the output you want? give us the sample. Both of your hash contains same `object_id`?

Comment: Still unclear. Do you want as output the same kind of array of hashes? Or do you want "a new hash" as you specified? This confusion could have been avoided if you simply provided the output you're looking for.

Comment: Your data are not valid Ruby expression (until dbenhur's edit, which happened after I posted this comment).

Comment: But dbenhur, are you sure that is the right edit? The OP may or may not have intended that. It might have been better to leave the question as inconmrehensible and wait until the OP fixes it.

Comment: @sawa It may not be what OP intends, but does seem the most obvious interpretation of the malformed literals.

Comment: By the way, my downvote is for the sloppyness of the question, and my closevote is for the lack of question in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
merge = data1.dup
xref = {}
data2.each { |hash| xref[hash["object_id"]] = hash }
merge.each do |hash|
  oid = hash["object_id"]
  hash2 = xref[oid]
  if hash2
    hash2.each_pair do |kk, vv|
      next if "object_id" == kk
      hash[kk] = vv
    end
  end
end
```

Running this code using your data and issuing:

```
pp merge
```

produces:

```
[{"pid"=>"126199850741820_2172905",
  "object_id"=>606621809366286,
  "xcoord"=>81.885856079404,
  "ycoord"=>51.116625310174,
  "name"=>"321"},
 {"pid"=>"126199850741820_2172905",
  "object_id"=>606621809366286,
  "xcoord"=>81.885856079404,
  "ycoord"=>51.116625310174,
  "name"=>"321"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
require "pp"

data1 = [{"pid"=>"126199850741820_2172905", "object_id"=>606621809366286, "xcoord"=>81.885856079404, "ycoord"=>51.116625310174},{"pid"=>"126199850741820_2172905", "object_id"=>606621809366286, "xcoord"=>81.885856079404, "ycoord"=>51.116625310174}]
data2 = [{"object_id" => 606621809366286, "name" => "123"},{"object_id" => 606621809366286, "name" => "321"}]

pp data1.map{|h| data2.map{|i| h.merge(i) if i["object_id"]==h["object_id"]}.last}
```

***Output:***

```
[{"pid"=>"126199850741820_2172905",
  "object_id"=>606621809366286,
  "xcoord"=>81.885856079404,
  "ycoord"=>51.116625310174,
  "name"=>"321"},
 {"pid"=>"126199850741820_2172905",
  "object_id"=>606621809366286,
  "xcoord"=>81.885856079404,
  "ycoord"=>51.116625310174,
  "name"=>"321"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the fact that your example has all four hashes with the same ID is a mistake, or actually irrelevant and what you really want is for each hash in data1 to be merged with the hash in data2 with the same index.

This is then what you want:

```
data1.zip(data2).map{|a| a[0].merge(a[1])}
```

Output:

```
[{"pid"=>"126199850741820_2172905",
  "object_id"=>606621809366286,
  "xcoord"=>81.885856079404,
  "ycoord"=>51.116625310174,
  "name"=>"123"},
 {"pid"=>"126199850741820_2172905",
  "object_id"=>606621809366286,
  "xcoord"=>81.885856079404,
  "ycoord"=>51.116625310174,
  "name"=>"321"}]
```